# Retrofit. POST. Android. Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, post, retrofit, retrofit2

Существует запрос POST на сервер с помощью библиотеки Retrofit. Если запрос выполнен успешно, то возвращается некий объект с данными. НО если какая-то ошибка, например, неверный код был передан, то ответ будет в виде НЕ объекта (это и так понятно), а в виде строки. К примеру, "wrong_code".

Как можно получить текст ошибки (я имею ввиду строку "wrong_code", к примеру)?

Любая ошибка отправляется в блок кода, где эти ошибки обрабатываются, необходимо их как-то определить, что можете посоветовать в этой ситуации?

Запрос выполняется с помощью библиотеки JavaRX

```
fun doAuth(key: String, id: String, authRequest: AuthRequest) {
    postAPI.setAuth(key, id, authRequest)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            view.onSuccessful()
        }, {
            view.onFailure(it.message!!)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка от сервера приходит как обычный `Json`, вы можете распарсить ее в свой кастомный объект ошибки и работать с ним так как вам это необходимо.

Вот небольшой пример:

```
private fun parseResponse(response: Response<RESPONSE>): RESPONSE {
        val data: RESPONSE?

        if (response.isSuccessful)
            data = response.body()
        else
            throw getNetworkException(response)
    }
```

Где **`RESPONSE`** это дженерик тайп. Вы можете так и оставить, либо же заменить его конкретным типом. Здесь я написал свой кастомный `NetworkProvider` который отлавливает результат от каждого запроса и парсит его в нужный мне ответ.

```
private fun getNetworkException(response: Response<RESPONSE>): NetworkException {
        val type = object : TypeToken<NetworkException>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(response.errorBody()!!.charStream(), type)
    }
```

Здесь как раз и происходит парсинг ответа с ошибкой.
Ниже собственно мой кастомный объект ошибки:

```
data class NetworkException(
    @SerializedName("status_code") val statusCode: Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("status_message") val statusMessage: String = "",
    @SerializedName("success") val isSuccessful: Boolean = false
) : Exception()
```

В вашем случае это может быть объект вроде такого:

```
data class NetworkException(
        @SerializedName("status_message") val statusMessage: String = ""
    ) : Exception()
```